# bitcoin with stripe Error: The source you provided is not in a chargeable state in node.js

Tags: node.js

Bitcoin with stripe 
Error: The source you provided is not in a chargeable state in node.js...
I m new in Node.js and using payment with Bitcoin using stripe.. and how I go to chargeable state and Is it chargeable state works on sandbox mode

```js
 stripe.sources.create({
                    type: "bitcoin",
                    amount: amount,
                    currency: "usd",
                    owner: {
                        email: req.body.stripeEmail
                    }
                }).then(function(source){
                    console.log("inside source");
                    console.log(source);
                     return stripe.charges.create({
                        amount: source.amount,
                        currency: source.currency,
                        source: source.id
                    }).then(function(charge) {
                        console.log("inside charge");
                        console.log(charge);
                        return res.redirect('/user');
                    }).catch(function(err){
                        next(err);
                    }); 
                 }).catch(function(err){
                        next(err);
                    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I didn't test bitcoins, but worked with stripe.
https://stripe.com/docs/sources/bitcoin - at this page you can find "Step 3: Charge the Source". I think you have to setup webhook and wait for event "source.chargeable". After getting this event you can make a charge.

Regarding your source code:
I think this code will be broken into 2 parts. One will make the source and will do this action by URL1, another, that will be available by URL2 -  will handle event "source.chargeable".

Hope this will help :)

Comment: Can you make bitcoin code with its source in the stripe? I tried but it is not charging the money with bitcoin_source. may be it doesn't work in test mode. could you please help me.